# Overloading the == operator

Tags: c++

I am trying to compare member variables of 2 objects from the same class

in Donor.h

```
friend bool operator==(const Donor& donor1,const Donor& donor2);
```

And in Donor.cpp

```
bool Donor::operator==(const Donor& donor1, const Donor& donor2)
{
    if (donor1.get_type() == donor2.get_type())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

but i get an comple error

```
bool Donor::operator==(const Donor& donor1, const Donor& donor2) must have exactly one argument.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: when you add an operator method to a class, you just need to pass the second operand as parameter

Comment: An overloaded `operator==()` is either a non-static member function that accepts one argument, or function (not a non-static member) that accepts two arguments.  No other options.    A friend function is a non-member function.  You have implemented it as a non-static member function that accepts two arguments, which is not one of the acceptable options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `friend` function is not a member function. It cannot be defined as `Donor::operator==`, it must be just `operator==`.

The error message is less than helpful here. It is saying that a `operator==` member function only takes a single argument, but since you do not want to make it a member function, that is information you do not need.

Comment: Agreed error message no help. Working fine now thank you.

Comment: Disagree that the error message doesn't help, but you have to work out how to interpret it.   It's telling you the compiler thinks you're implementing `operator==()` in a manner that it should only have one argument, but you've given it two.      If you think the function does X and the compiler is informing you it thinks the function you've given it does Y, then the problem is that somehow you've told it to do the wrong thing.     Of course, it is tempting to blame the tools you're using (the compiler) rather than your mistake in using it.

Comment: @Peter I understand what's wrong, how to fix it, and why the compiler gives the message it does. I didn't say it's entirely useless, but there are much better messages that *could* be given here, and when other compilers *do* give better messages, it's fair to call that out. Intel gives the message "error: class "S" has no member "operator=="" (for a sample program to reproduce the OP's error), which I consider much better.